# Discord py | Get message by ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a giveaway system for my discord bot.
I save the end time for running giveaways in a mysql database and when the end time equals the current time the bot calls a function to end the giveaway.
In the database I store the message-, channel- and server ID. Now the question.
How do I get the discord.Message from the ID?
I tried following but this doesn't seem to work:

```
giveaway_msg = bot.fetch_message(db_giveaway_message_ID)
```

db_giveaway_message_ID is the Message ID (904081961583251456)

**EDIT**

Current Code (still not working)

```
async def giveaway_end(giveaway_db_fetch):
    print('Giveaway End startet')
    db_giveaway_message_ID = giveaway_db_fetch[4]
    db_giveaway_starter = giveaway_db_fetch[3]
    fb_giveaway_channel_ID = giveaway_db_fetch[5]
    db_giveaway_price = giveaway_db_fetch[1]
    print(db_giveaway_message_ID)
    
    giveaway_msg_channel = await bot.get_channel(fb_giveaway_channel_ID)
    print(f'Giveaway Message Channel = {giveaway_msg_channel.name}')
    giveaway_msg = await giveaway_msg_channel.fetch_message(db_giveaway_message_ID)
    print(f'Message found: {giveaway_msg.id}')
```

It does print the messageID but nothing more happens. -no error-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that you can't use **bot**.fetch_message, because when you want to fetch the message you have to call the **channel** (where the message was sent), the **member** (that sent this message) or **context** if it's used in a command.

Also, your current code works as expected (you wanted it to print the message-id). You properly fetched the `discord.Message` you just have to do something with it, other than only printing the id.

---

**Fetch message:**

```py
giveaway_msg_channel = bot.get_channel(fb_giveaway_channel_ID)
giveaway_msg = await giveaway_msg_channel.fetch_message(db_giveaway_message_ID)
```

**If you want to get the message content then:**

```py
print(f'Message found: {giveaway_msg.content}')
```

**or author of the message:**

```py
print(f'Message found: {giveaway_msg.author}')
```

[Check discord.Message in documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Message)

Comment: `bot.get_channel()` doesn't need to be awaited, it retrieves the channel from the internal cache. You're probably thinking of `guild.fetch_channel()`which is an API request.

Comment: Yeah, I used `fetch_channel`, but then changed it to `get_channel` and forgot to remove `await`. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, so it works like that... But the main problem was that the message and channel ids were given as strings and not as integers. Thanks for the help <3